# Altura Flash not working for Canon T3

Tags: canon, flash, troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, canon-1100d

I have an [Altura Flash](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HK0A6LQ) and use it with my Canon T3. It was working fine for the last 6 months without any problems. In the last 2 days, it hangs after 2-3 clicks. I used TTL mode. I already tried all modes but same things happen - after 2-4 click my flash hangs. Nothing works. I can't even turn the flash off.

I've tried so many things but nothing has worked. Can anyone please help me? Any suggestion? Any solution?

[[image]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your flash is broken. Since it would probably cost more to have it fixed than what you paid for it, it's time to buy a new flash. Getting two years out of a third party Chinese flash is not too bad if you've used it regularly.

Only getting six months is catching the short end of the straw. You can try to contact the seller and see if they will repair/replace it.

Many of the sellers of cheap Chinese flashes require you to ship them back to Hong Kong or China at your own expense, which becomes a significant portion of the cost of a new flash. You'll then wait several months to get it back.

Comment: `Getting two years`, yeah, except he used it for just 6 months, that's not a good deal... Sometimes it's just not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I purchased this from Amazon and contact directly manufacture ( Altura Photos ) they ready to replace my flash.. Thanks once again for your input and tym.!!

Answer (score 1):

==>> Service center. I'm afraid this is not something you can fix yourself. It should be covered by the warranty, so I think it's your best bet.

Sometimes it's just not worth buying cheap stuff...

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I purchased this from Amazon and contact directly manufacture ( Altura Photos ) they ready to replace my flash.. Thanks once again for your input and tym.!!